# list-style & bullet effect with proper text alignment

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, user-interface

```css
.lists li{
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .lists li:before {
        content: '\00b7';
        font-size: 140px;
        line-height: 60px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: #114576;
        /* margin-left: -5.5%; */
    }
    .lists ul{
        padding-top: 2%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lists">
 <ul>
  <li class="text-muted">In 2016, SAF lent technical support to the Government of Maharashtra  by assisting them with test interpretation, as well as the development of the Maha Mitra Career Portal and the setup of the student helpline for counseling</li>
  <li class="text-muted">In 2017, we have entered the next stage of development with a unique 7-field interest test, developed in collaboration with the Department of Psychology at the Savitribai Phule Pune University</li>
  <li class="text-muted">In the last 2 years, more than 32 lakh grade 10 students from over 22000 State Board schools, as well as students appearing externally for the grade 10 exam, have taken the interest test</li>
  <li class="text-muted">Students can access the        results of the interest test on the Maha Career Mitra Portal (www.mahacareermitra.in) -  a special portal developed by SAF which lists 83,000 government approved higher educational options available in Maharashtra</li>
  <li class="text-muted">These courses are further mapped to the student’s relevant district and assessed interest</li>
  <li class="text-muted">The portal also serves as a rich source of information, with numerous videos and articles on the 7 education fields (Arts, Commerce, Fine Arts, Technical, Health Sciences, Agriculture and Uniform Services)</li>
  <li class="text-muted">SAF maintains a dedicated helpline that offers students one-on-one counseling with trained career counselors from the Institute of Vocational Guidance and Selection (IVGS)</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

[image: image describe the desired output]

here i have implemented the code for the designing the paragraph with bullets.but,i am facing some problem like the second line taking top space between two lines as well the text is not appearing in proper alignment as like displayed in image.
some css effects are missing to display the code same as like displayed in image.

Comment: i am new in designing profile the same effect i want to design as displayed in the image but cant due to less knowledge of css.plz help me

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display:flex` on the `li` and it will work. or use `display:table-row` see both solutions below

1. display:flex on `li`

```css
.lists li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.lists li:before {
  content: '\00b7';
  font-size: 140px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #114576;
  /* margin-left: -5.5%; */
}

.lists ul {
  padding-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul>
    <li class="text-muted">In 2016, SAF lent technical support to the Government of Maharashtra by assisting them with test interpretation, as well as the development of the Maha Mitra Career Portal and the setup of the student helpline for counseling</li>
    <li class="text-muted">In 2017, we have entered the next stage of development with a unique 7-field interest test, developed in collaboration with the Department of Psychology at the Savitribai Phule Pune University</li>
    <li class="text-muted">In the last 2 years, more than 32 lakh grade 10 students from over 22000 State Board schools, as well as students appearing externally for the grade 10 exam, have taken the interest test</li>
    <li class="text-muted">Students can access the results of the interest test on the Maha Career Mitra Portal (www.mahacareermitra.in) - a special portal developed by SAF which lists 83,000 government approved higher educational options available in Maharashtra</li>
    <li class="text-muted">These courses are further mapped to the student’s relevant district and assessed interest</li>
    <li class="text-muted">The portal also serves as a rich source of information, with numerous videos and articles on the 7 education fields (Arts, Commerce, Fine Arts, Technical, Health Sciences, Agriculture and Uniform Services)</li>
    <li class="text-muted">SAF maintains a dedicated helpline that offers students one-on-one counseling with trained career counselors from the Institute of Vocational Guidance and Selection (IVGS)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

2. display:table-row on `li` and display-table on `ul` ( but in this way you cannot add margins between `li`s because `table-row`s do not accept margins )

```css
.lists li {
  display: table-row;
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.lists li:before {
  content: '\00b7';
  font-size: 140px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #114576;
  display: table-cell;
  /* margin-left: -5.5%; */
}

.lists ul {
  padding-top: 2%;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <ul>
    <li class="text-muted">In 2016, SAF lent technical support to the Government of Maharashtra by assisting them with test interpretation, as well as the development of the Maha Mitra Career Portal and the setup of the student helpline for counseling</li>
    <li class="text-muted">In 2017, we have entered the next stage of development with a unique 7-field interest test, developed in collaboration with the Department of Psychology at the Savitribai Phule Pune University</li>
    <li class="text-muted">In the last 2 years, more than 32 lakh grade 10 students from over 22000 State Board schools, as well as students appearing externally for the grade 10 exam, have taken the interest test</li>
    <li class="text-muted">Students can access the results of the interest test on the Maha Career Mitra Portal (www.mahacareermitra.in) - a special portal developed by SAF which lists 83,000 government approved higher educational options available in Maharashtra</li>
    <li class="text-muted">These courses are further mapped to the student’s relevant district and assessed interest</li>
    <li class="text-muted">The portal also serves as a rich source of information, with numerous videos and articles on the 7 education fields (Arts, Commerce, Fine Arts, Technical, Health Sciences, Agriculture and Uniform Services)</li>
    <li class="text-muted">SAF maintains a dedicated helpline that offers students one-on-one counseling with trained career counselors from the Institute of Vocational Guidance and Selection (IVGS)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

let me know if these solutions worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it with [font aweseome](http://fontawesome.io) as well :

```css
.lists li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 2.3em;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}

.lists li:before {
  content: "\f111"; /* Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  color: #114576;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -2.3em;
  width: 2.3em;
}

.lists ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left:3em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="lists">
  <ul>
    <li class="text-muted">In 2016, SAF lent technical support to the Government of Maharashtra by assisting them with test interpretation, as well as the development of the Maha Mitra Career Portal and the setup of the student helpline for counseling</li>
    <li class="text-muted">In 2017, we have entered the next stage of development with a unique 7-field interest test, developed in collaboration with the Department of Psychology at the Savitribai Phule Pune University</li>
    <li class="text-muted">In the last 2 years, more than 32 lakh grade 10 students from over 22000 State Board schools, as well as students appearing externally for the grade 10 exam, have taken the interest test</li>
  <li class="text-muted">Students can access the        results of the interest test on the Maha Career Mitra Portal (www.mahacareermitra.in) -  a special portal developed by SAF which lists 83,000 government approved higher educational options available in Maharashtra</li>
  
  </ul>
</div>
```